# Drag event on MS Edge duplicating the "preview content" on 2nd/n drag

Tags: html, draggable, microsoft-edge

Hopefully someone can help, the following snippet word on chrome/FF/IE11 fine.

On edge, the 1st one is fine, the second (or sometimes third) on the drag preview still has the previous words in it which where dragged?

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FU78JD0SFVQM

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks[image]